Does Promise.resolve(1); involve microtask queue?
I am searching whether Promise.resolve(1); includes any mcirotask queue or not? There is no .then() or .catch() handler attached to it. Only Promise.resolve(1); Example:
const v = Promise.resolve(1);

According to ECMA 2024 specs, I have read following algos:

27.2.4.7 Promise.resolve ( x )
This function returns either a new promise resolved with the passed
argument, or the argument itself if the argument is a promise produced
by this constructor.
1. Let C be the this value.
2. If C is not an Object, throw a TypeError exception.
3. Return ? PromiseResolve(C, x).

Note This function expects its this value to be a constructor function
that supports the parameter conventions of the Promise constructor.
27.2.4.7.1 PromiseResolve ( C, x )
The abstract operation PromiseResolve takes arguments C (a
constructor) and x (an ECMAScript language value) and returns either a
normal completion containing an ECMAScript language value or a throw
completion. It returns a new promise resolved with x. It performs the
following steps when called:
1. If IsPromise(x) is true, then
a. Let xConstructor be ? Get(x, "constructor").
b. If SameValue(xConstructor, C) is true, return x.
2. Let promiseCapability be ? NewPromiseCapability(C).
3. Perform ? Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, « x »).
4. Return promiseCapability.[[Promise]].

27.2.1.3.2 Promise Resolve Functions
A promise resolve function is an anonymous built-in function that has
[[Promise]] and [[AlreadyResolved]] internal slots.
When a promise resolve function is called with argument resolution,
the following steps are taken:
1. Let F be the active function object.
2. Assert: F has a [[Promise]] internal slot whose value is an Object.
3. Let promise be F.[[Promise]].
4. Let alreadyResolved be F.[[AlreadyResolved]].
5. If alreadyResolved.[[Value]] is true, return undefined.
6. Set alreadyResolved.[[Value]] to true.
7. If SameValue(resolution, promise) is true, then
a. Let selfResolutionError be a newly created TypeError object.
b. Perform RejectPromise(promise, selfResolutionError).
c. Return undefined.
8. If resolution is not an Object, then
a. Perform FulfillPromise(promise, resolution).
b. Return undefined.
9. Let then be Completion(Get(resolution, "then")).
10. If then is an abrupt completion, then
a. Perform RejectPromise(promise, then.[[Value]]).
b. Return undefined.
11. Let thenAction be then.[[Value]].
12. If IsCallable(thenAction) is false, then
a. Perform FulfillPromise(promise, resolution).
b. Return undefined.
13. Let thenJobCallback be HostMakeJobCallback(thenAction).
14. Let job be NewPromiseResolveThenableJob(promise, resolution, thenJobCallback).
15. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(job.[[Job]], job.[[Realm]]).
16. Return undefined.
The "length" property of a promise resolve function is 1.

see step 8.a
27.2.1.4 FulfillPromise ( promise, value )
The abstract operation FulfillPromise takes arguments promise (a
Promise) and value (an ECMAScript language value) and returns unused.
It performs the following steps when called:
1. Assert: The value of promise.[[PromiseState]] is pending.
2. Let reactions be promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]].
3. Set promise.[[PromiseResult]] to value.
4. Set promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]] to undefined.
5. Set promise.[[PromiseRejectReactions]] to undefined.
6. Set promise.[[PromiseState]] to fulfilled.
7. Perform TriggerPromiseReactions(reactions, value).
8. Return unused.


Am I right in saying that Promise.resolve(1) does not include any microtask?

Try -> Promise.resolve('there').then(r => console.log(r)); console.log('hello')  Notice how this says hello there.   The creation of promise itself doesn't get queued, but the then callbacks get executed during the microtask queue getting drained before the next event loop.

If on the above if you add setTimeout(() => console.log('everyone')); to the start, you will see how it now says hello there everyone, this is because the timeout will be using the macrotask queue instead and this has lower priority than the microtask and gets processed during the next event loop.

IOW: Promise.resolve(1); does indeed not include any microtasks, it's wherever you have any then callbacks attached that it becomes relevant, and its when processing the microtask queue.  Note it might also be worth pointing out the processing of the microtask queue is actually sync, and not async, even thought it feels async..

@Keith, that seems an uncommon definition of "sync" that you use there.

@trincot  Maybe, what word would you suggest instead?.  Basically I'm just pointing out the queue is not processed asynchronously, IOW: you can even lock up your browser if you chained the promises without any real async Op's in between.

My understanding is that in the JavaScript world the term asynchronous applies whenever a function is executed/resumed by the engine when it processes a job queue, no matter which job queue. If your point is that the priority of the microtask queue is greater than that for UI events, then I would just say it like that.

@aLearner, it seems by quoting the specs you have answered your own question.

@trincot  async to me is the main event loop running,  the microtasks get executed before the next event loop.  If the specs say processing the microtask queue is classed as async, then so be it.  But personally don't think that makes any sense.

It makes much sense to me though.

@trincot   const delay = () => {const t = Date.now()+1000; while (Date.now() < t);};  for (let l = 0; l < 10; l ++) { Promise.resolve().then(r => delay()) }  This will lock a browser for 10 seconds, if processing the microtask queue was async this should have only locked it for 1 second 10 times.  eg.  using a setTimeout with l*1000 would indeed do that.  So for me the distinction is more than just a priority thing.  And regardless of terminology that was the point I was trying to make.

Sure, I understand your point. It just sounds so confusing that you have a different concept of asynchrony.

@trincot  For me if something is async, its something that allows the main threads event loop to continue, this was the case for when I coded in C, and had to mess with PeekMessage / Postmessage etc.   In Javascript you have things like fetch / setTimeout etc, that I believe are async, and don't block the main event loop.  And is why I wanted to make the distinction that setTimeout(fn) is not going to work the same as Promise.resolve().then().  A better example -> https://shorturl.at/hnj6R

Like I wrote, I understand your point. You're just using a different concept of "asynchronous", and relate it to blocking UI. To me that is a different concept. In your view a then callback coud be executed synchronously. But by the common use "asynchronous" in the JavaScript community, a then callback is always executed asynchronously. See for instance how the word asynchronous is used in point 3.1 in the Promises/A+ specification.

I think what keith wants to point out here is that .then() is asynchronous but WITHIN the microtask queue ITSELF is sync. Am i wrong?

@trincot  In that 3.1 did you notice -> Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.  The setTimeout technique hasn't been used in browsers for a long time now.  In some respects if is just -> const q = [() => console.log('one'),() => console.log('two')]; for (const fn of q) fn(); that is run before next tick.  The only difference is that queue is drained by the browser.  So you wouldn't class that bit of code as async would you?.

@trincot maybe the issue here is what you consider code wise to be async, and what modern browsers do with Promises.  From my understanding there is no async code at all been used in the Promise implementation on modern browsers.  In most cases the distinction wouldn't matter, after all why create a promise for none async code.  But like I pointed if you have conditional promises that sometime do real async and sometimes do pure sync code, there is the potential to lock up the browser, or node event loop.  I've had it happen to me, and is the reason for the warning.

@Keith The definition of "asynchronous" is that code is executed outside of the normal program flow, after the called function has already returned. That applies both to microtasks and macrotasks.

My point is that it states that then calls are asynchronous. Always. It mentions microtask as implementation, but that doesn't change the concept of what is asynchronous. The key words are "fresh stack". I understand what you are saying, but you consistently use the word asynchronous in a different way from what I consider the standard use (like in the Promises/A+ implementation).

@trincot Then I go back to my original question, what terminology would you use for the blocking nature of draining the microtask queue?.   For me sync / async seems so logical, the draining for the event queue is using synchronous execution..  Actually I might have just answered my own question,.. What I should have said is blocking, does that help.?

Yes, "blocking" the user-interface events is what you mean. It is a different concept. But realise that even if you post a callback in a lower priority queue, like with setTimeout, you also block user events during the time that JavaScript code executes. The difference is that lower-priorty events may get served before that code starts executing. But once it does, it is blocking as well.

@Bergi Asynchronous computing is a paradigm where a user doesn't expect a workload to be executed immediately. Instead, the workload is scheduled for execution in the near future without blocking the application's latency-critical path  Now, for me the application latency-critial path I would assume is the event loop.  And it does block it.  Anyway, I think I've made my point, and if the terminology in JS is as said, then fair enough.

@Keith you're basically right, it is synchronous, but only if you take the event loop as reference. For the user's script (which matters for most of us here), then it's async. Note that there is no prioritization system at all though between microtasks and tasks. Just like you can have multiple callbacks fire in a single task for the same event, you can have many microtasks run in a single task, so your model is actually closer to the truth than theirs. Where even a user-blocking task would not block the UI for more than a few rendering frames, a microtasks loop will.

@Kaiido  That's why right at the start I said -> even thought it feels async.   I'm glad somebody get's what I was saying.. :)  I know its a minor point, and in some respects wondered if I should have said it.  The only reason I did say it though, is it has actually caught me out once with a very hard  to find bug.  I basically had some conditional logic in an infinite async loop, and browser would randomly hang.  The solution of course was to periodically call a macrotask like a setTimeout (Promise sleep), a terminology I believe called allowing the event loop the breath.

No, Promise.resolve(1) does not involve any microtasks. As you concluded correctly, it just returns a fulfilled promise: the promise is constructed and then resolved (in particular: immediately fulfilled) without any reactions to schedule, before Promise.resolve returns.

27.2.1.4 FulfillPromise ( promise, value ) contains 7. Perform TriggerPromiseReactions(reactions, value). and in 27.2.1.8 TriggerPromiseReactions ( reactions, argument ) steps are 1. For each element reaction of reactions, do a. Let job be NewPromiseReactionJob(reaction, argument). b. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(job.[[Job]], job.[[Realm]]).. The reactions here will be undefined as concluded from 27.2.1.4 FulfillPromise ( promise, value ). SO what will be behaviour of 1. For each element reaction of reactions, do in TriggerPromiseReactions(reactions, value)?

No, it's not "undefined". It's initialised to an empty list in the constructor, and therefore the loop over that list simply does nothing.

But why it will go to 27.2.3.1 Promise ( executor )? I am using Promise.resolve(1) as stated in my initial problem so it should go to 27.2.4.7 Promise.resolve ( x ) according to which following statement is being executed 4. Set promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]] to undefined?

It goes into the promise constructor during NewPromiseCapability(C). Notice the promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]] = undefined happens only after "Let reactions be promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]" which is the empty list that's being passed to TriggerPromiseReactions.
